# Let $N|K$ a field extension and $G=Aut_K(N)$ finite. For every field L such that $K\subset L\subset N$, prove the equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Prove the equivalence.

> (i) N|L is Galois (normal and separable extension)
> (ii) $k(G) \subset L$, where's k(G) is the fixed field of G.

The $(i)\Rightarrow (ii)$ part going well using a the Galois Correspondence. But the conversely i have difficult to make it and prove that is separable and normal. Any hint?

Ps: Feel free to correct my english, will help me to improve future questions.

Comment: Easy to see that $N/N^G$ is separable, as $a\in N$ is a root of the separable polynomial $\prod_{b\in Ga} (x-b)\in N^G[x]$.

Easy to see that it is normal as well (every element of $N$ is the root of some polynomial $\in N^G[x]$ that splits completely in $N$).

If $N^G\subset L\subset N$ then $N/L$ is separable and normal.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the definition of the notation $Ga$? My book has some strange notations and i don't see that here.

Comment: $Ga = \{ g(a),g\in G\}$